# Prevent Windows 7 from sleep + power button hook

Tags: windows-7

I'm used to not shutdown Windows but to sleeping it. I set up power button (PB) action to do it. When I want to shutdown I must go to start -> Shutdown. That's OK.

Now I think of a mechanism that will be hooked up to a PB. Should be started after I press PB but before OS will go to sleep. Something that will check few conditions (i.e. running backup, running AV scan, ...) and if true (something is running) prevent go to sleep.

Optionally:
It would be nice to start the same "mechanism" before restart and shutdown (invoked not only from Start menu, but also by other software (i.e. installers) but with option to allow some sources (i.e. UPS software)

Generally: How to run something after PowerButton but before Sleeping. How to code (C#.NET, vbs, batch (preferred)) sleep prevention (cancellation).

Comment: I can explain how to prevent Windows 7 automatically shutting down your Programs when you by accident press the shut down button. I know also how to stop Windows 7 from entering hibernation mode when a specific process is running (through Terminal). There is also a program that prevents Windows 7 from going to sleep when it is busy. But i am not sure if you are looking for this solutions. If you are interested i will post it here.

Comment: Yes, Devid. Please share the secret. I'll try your ideas/apps. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it may happen that you shut down your Windows 7 unintentionally. Windows 7 will then automatically shut down all your programs and and you might loose changes. But you can prevent this from happening. Here is how it is done:

#### Turn Off Auto Closing of Programs at Shutdown in Windows 7

Windows 7 Professional:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button and type in the search `gpedit.msc`. Right click on it and run with Administrator rights. Now go to ***Computer Configuration*** → ***Administrative Templates*** → ***System*** → ***Shutdown Options***. In the right hand side pane, you will find a value *Turn off automatic termination of applications that block or cancel shutdown*. Double click on it and choose Enabled. Click OK to save the settings and close the dialog.

[image: gpedit.msc Turn Auto Closing of Programs]

Windows 7 Home Edition:

- For this version of Windows 7 you will have to hack the registry or
  just download [**turnoff_autoclose_policy_win7.zip**](http://www.trishtech.com/download.php?f=turnoff_autoclose_policy_win7.zip). Just
  extract it on your desktop and double click on 
  turnoff_autoclose_policy_win7.reg and click 'YES'. This will
  automatically add a New → DWORD (32-bit Value) to the registry key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`.

#### Powercfg Command-Line Options

- In the command line you can type `POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS
  name_of_the_process Display System` and this will prevent Windows 7
  to go to sleep while a certain process is running. I never used it so
  you must read the manual [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

  **Usage**: `POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE <CALLER_TYPE> <NAME> <REQUEST>`   Specifies one of the following caller type:
  PROCESS, SERVICE, DRIVER. This is obtained by calling the POWERCFG
  -REQUESTS command.  Specifies the caller name. This is the name returned from calling POWERCFG -REQUESTS command.  Specifies
  one or more of the following Power. Request Types: Display, System,
  Awaymode.

  Example: POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS wmplayer.exe Display
  System

  To remove the power request override, use the -REQUESTSOVERRIDE
  option, but do not specify any type of override (System, Display,
  AwayMode) as in the following example: `POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE
  PROCESS wmplayer.exe`

Comment: 1. "Turn Off Auto Closing of Programs at Shutdown in Windows 7" -> I want programs to be closed automatically on shutdown. Exceprion is when backup is running.
3. "Insomnia" -> First thought: start insomnia, backup, kill insomnia. Then a read that Insomnia will not interrupt user-requested sleep or shutdown. On the other hand there is source code available...
2. This looks interesting, but decription is not 100% clear for me. I need to sit and make some testing.
4. BIG THANX for this ideas!