# Let any exe prevent system sleep/hibernation in windows

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, process, power-management

Is there a way to have Windows system standby prevented in the event that a particular executable is still running?

I know playing videos does this semi-automatically but I'd like to apply this functionality to another executable that I have running sometimes that requires a good deal of time before it's done. As such, I'd like to not have to manually disable sleep/hibernate while still letting a screensaver come on.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/561165/160458 - went with the pwrcfg route and it works great.

Comment: Update: doesn't work great. Pain to use repeatedly and seems unreliable/imprecise with little feedback.