# Where are changes made by the PWRCFG.EXE command line utility stored?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, process, power-management

Specifically in regards to the below part of [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/561165/160458), is there somewhere I can manually set/edit what this utility is doing?

Powercfg Command-Line Options

In the command line you can type

```
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS name_of_the_process
```

Display System and this will prevent
Windows 7 to go to sleep while a certain process is running. I never
used it so you must read the manual [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Usage:

```
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE <CALLER_TYPE> <NAME> <REQUEST>
```

Specifies one of the following caller type: PROCESS, SERVICE, DRIVER.
This is obtained by calling the POWERCFG -REQUESTS command. Specifies
the caller name. This is the name returned from calling POWERCFG
 -REQUESTS command. Specifies one or more of the following Power. Request Types: Display, System, Awaymode.

Example:

```
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS wmplayer.exe Display System
```

To remove the power request override, use the -REQUESTSOVERRIDE option,
but do not specify any type of override (System, Display, AwayMode)
as in the following example:

```
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS wmplayer.exe
```

Comment: How would you manually set it? Why not just use the command line program?

Comment: @nhinkle - Well the command line obviously makes some change somewhere, registry or other (not sure). What if I were to forget one of the things I changed and needed to find out what it was to change it back?

Comment: I suppose. I think it resets after each reboot, and you can remove them too. I'll put a possible solution below though.

Comment: @nhinkle - Is there a way to make it permanent until removed? Assuming it doesn't of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) to capture the changes.

> RegFromApp monitors the Registry changes made by the application that
>   you selected, and creates a standard RegEdit registration file (.reg)
>   that contains all the Registry changes made by the application. You
>   can use the generated .reg file to import these changes with RegEdit
>   when it's needed.

[image]

A different way would be the create 2 registry snapshost with [RegShot 2](http://www.wincert.net/forum/files/file/16-regshot2-unicode/) (1 before and 1 after the change) and let the Tool compare the snapshots and list the differences.

Answer (score 12):

Although it's great that other answers tell which tools can be used to try to find out the answer, they don't actually answer where the information is stored.

The overrides are stored under the Process, Service, and Driver keys in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerRequestOverride\
```

Each override is a DWORD named by the name of the process and with a value that is the combination of [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_power_request_type):

- 1 = DISPLAY
- 2 = SYSTEM
- 4 = AWAYMODE
- 8 = EXECUTION

Thus the example command:

```
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS wmplayer.exe Display System
```

Produces this result in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerRequestOverride\Process]
"wmplayer.exe"=dword:00000003
```

At time of writing this is still applicable to the latest version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Monitor from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what the `pwrcfg.exe` program is doing when it sets these options. Use the filtering options to only monitor `pwrcfg.exe`, and see where in the registry or file system it's saving the configuration options.