# How to prevent windows from sleeping?

Tags: windows-8, sleep

How I can prevent my laptop from sleeping when a large file is downloading?
Notice that I use `windows 8` and the downloader program is `IDM`
where I can find the related settings, in `IDM` or `Windows`?
Thanks for any help

Comment: I found these results when doing some research on the subject http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-sleep-mode/28b81f3e-cc6c-4dde-be30-e002a353ab05 and www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI3YQx1dyO8

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question except that it has been asked in many forms already: http://superuser.com/a/561165/160458

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to:

`Control panel` -> `System and security` -> `Power Settings`(or press  [image: image3]  + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `powercfg.cpl` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

In screen click it:
[image]
Then change the option of `Put the computer to sleep` to `Never`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool ["Don't Sleep":](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep)

> Don't Sleep is a small portable program to prevent system shutdown,
>   Standby, Hibernate, Turn Off and Restart.
>
> Especially when old Programs run on Windows-7 or Windows Vista. Here's
>   more aggressive power-saving features with new rules.
>
> But not only that, it also prevents loggin off the computer, and the
>   deactivation of the monitor or activation of the screen saver.
>
> Of course you can also manually disable all the options and then
>   activate again, but with Don't Sleep one can save now many hand moves
>   and also save time! And it's easier than ever.
>
> Apart from the fact Don't Sleep has a timer that allows time control
>   unblock, or shutdown the computer for a specified time.

[image]