# How to prevent windows from locking / sleeping (without admin privileges)

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, lock

I know it is possible to [disable auto log out from control panel](https://superuser.com/questions/620413/how-to-prevent-windows-from-sleeping). I want to know is there a way to prevent windows from locking/ sleeping **without changing any security options**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download and run this little program: **No Sleep**

**Get it from here**

[No Sleep - Cnet](https://download.cnet.com/No-Sleep/3000-2094_4-75220774.html)

[No Sleep - Apponic](https://no-sleep.apponic.com/)

It moves your mouse once a minute by one pixel. Thus it prevents your windows from going to sleep mode.

Comment: This program seems can no longer be accessed in its original location. It says permission denied.

Comment: @JIXiang, I found a copy here of this file here: [Todd Cramer’s Blog](http://thecramers.us/windows/prevent-windows-screen-timeout-and-sleep-mode-nosleep-exe/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this AutoHotkey script:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
Loop
{
    ; Move mouse
    MouseMove, 1, 1, 0, R
    ; Replace mouse to its original location
    MouseMove, -1, -1, 0, R
    ; Wait before moving the mouse again
    Sleep, 600000
}
return
```

You can download the portable version of AutoHotkey [here](https://autohotkey.com/download/ahk.zip).

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link for Todd Cramer's blog (which is http://thecramers.us/windows/prevent-windows-screen-timeout-and-sleep-mode-nosleep-exe/ ) , it takes you to a page that has nothing to do with Todd Cramer or his software. Presumably because his domain-name or web-hosting expired.

However, when I downloaded the NoSleep program back in 2017, I also took screencaps of his webpage, and I made it a point to keep the downloaded file handy.

Since his site is down, I've hosted it on my Mediafire account.

You can access it via:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/vym9ft7coh6s84z/(keep+mouse+moving+to+avoid+screensaver)+--+NoSleep_0+(Archive+file+of+NoSleep+hosted+on+MediaFire+).rar/file

OR

via this URL-shortcut:
https://waa.ai/NoSleepOnMediafire

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

This can be done by the following:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Click on Power Options
3. Click on Change plan settings (to which ever plan is selected)
4. Change 'Put the computer to sleep' on NEVER
5. Click Save Changes

Comment: Which requires admin access. and i dont want that.

Comment: Then it's policy driven and you won't be able to without the correct access rights. @NikiteshKolpe

Comment: I think this should be the best answer since it relies on some inherent mechanism of Windows instead of any third-party tools.

Comment: @JIXiang I disagree, it doesn't answer the question being how to prevent Windows from sleeping **without admin rights**.